# How to improve the performance of a query on SQL Server with a table with 150 million records?

Tags: sql-server, bigdata

How can I improve my select query in a table with more 150 million records in SQL Server? I need to run a simple select and retrieve the result in the minimum time as possible. Should I create some index? Table partition? What do you guys recommend for that?

Here is my current scenario:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_name]
(
    [id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [key] [VARCHAR](20) NOT NULL,
    [text_value] [TEXT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_table_name] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)    
) 
GO
```

Select:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    text_value 
FROM 
    table_name (NOLOCK) 
WHERE
    key = @Key
```

Additional info:

1. That table won't have updates or deletes
2. The column `text_value` has a Json that will be retrieved on the Select and an application will handle this info
3. No other queries will run on that table, just the query above to retrieve always the `text_value` based on `key` column
4. Every 2 or 3 months about 15 millions are added to the table

Comment: Is Key unique? If so a unique index would probably be faster. Should result in a direct read which wouldn't care if its billions of rows, should still be instant. Also, if you know that the old data is never (or rarely) referenced then yes you could partition it, but you would need some additional columns to partition on.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that query:

```
SELECT top 1 text_value FROM table_name (NOLOCK) where key = @Key
```

I would add the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table_name (key)
INCLUDE (text_value);
```

The lookup will always be on the `key` column so that will form the index structure, and you want to include the `text_value` but not have it in the non-leaf pages.  This should always result in an index seek without a key lookup (a covering index).

Also, do not use the TEXT data type as it will be removed in a future version, use VARCHAR(MAX) instead.  Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @MJM what about Memory Optimize Table?